# Getline is not working

Tags: c++

I am using visual studio 2012 but whenever I use getline function there is no pause even loop next to it is also not running.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

void check_a()
{
    char a [50]; 
    int i =0 , ca=0; 
    cout <<"Enter a phrase"; 
    cin.getline (a,49); 
    while (a [i]!='\0'){
        if(a [i]=='a')
            a++; 
        i++; 
    }
    cout <<"Letter \'a\' occurs "<<a <<" times in this phrase"; 
}

int main()
{
    check_a (); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Output

```
Enter a phraseLetter 'a' occurs 0 times in this phrase
```

Any fixes or alternatives?

Comment: try replacing `cin.getline (a); ` with `cin >> a`. please let me know how that goes

Comment: You need to post real code instead of fantasy code. The shown code won't even compile, since `a` is declared twice in `check_a()`, as two variables of different type, with the same name. You need to post real code, instead of wasting everyone's time. Fail.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik this is *his* real code, he is asking us why it doesn't work. please don't be so discouraging

Comment: It is not real code. He claims it's real code that doesn't execute correctly. The problem is that real code compiles, this one doesn't, with obvious syntax errors. Try to compile the shown code, and reproduce the claimed results. You can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem multiple times and I have found that usually to fix this you just need to put:

```
cin.clear();
cin.sync();
```

Before the getline();

Answer (score 0):

`getline` is working perfectly.

Replace  `a++;` with `ca++;` to get the correct output.

Variable `ca` is your intended counter.